# Getting Enum class from generic type?

Tags: java, reflection, enums, java-8, getconstructor

Suppose I have several classes:

```
Class ExceptionA{
    public ExceptionA(ExceptionA.ErrorCode errorCode){}
    setters...
    getters...
    public static enum ErrorCode{
        EC_ABC,EC_XYZ,EC_123
}

Class ExceptionB{
    public ExceptionB(ExceptionB.ErrorCode errorCode){}
    setters...
    getters...
    public static enum ErrorCode{
        EC_DEF,EC_LOL,EC_456
}
```

In a loop somewhere that works with an array containing ExceptionA, ExceptionB, ExceptionC objects: I want to generically construct an Exception object using its constructor without ever explicitly stating `ExceptionX.ErrorCode`.

```
Class<? extends Exception> expectedException = exception.getClass().getConstructor(Enum.class).newInstance(someErrorCodeEnum);
```

The issue occurs at getConstructor(). Constructors do exist for each Exception class, but they take SpecificException.ErrorCode type. Not just a generic Enum.class. Is there some method that might work like this?:

```
ExceptionA exceptionAobject = new ExceptionA(EC_ABC);
exceptionAobject.getEnumClassFromString("ErrorCode"); // Should be of type ExceptionA.ErrorCode
```

Comment: There might be some bean introspection API that might work. Otherwise, you'll need to get the constructors with `getConstructors()`, looping through them to find one where the parameter type is a subtype of `Enum`, and use that one.

Comment: Is the use of different error code enums the *only* difference between your exception classes, or may there be other differences too?

Comment: I haven't noticed any yet, but there _may_ be other differences. I just want to account for the possibility of those as well.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the circumstances. If you know for sure that there will be only a single constructor, you could simply call, e.g. `ExceptionA.class.getConstructors()[0]` to get the sole constructor. You could even call `getParameterTypes()[0]` on the constructor object to get the actual `ErrorCode` type.

Otherwise, if you know that there should be an inner class named `ErrorCode`, you have to use the [Binary name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#name) of the inner class, i.e.

```
Class<? extends Exception> exceptionType = exception.getClass();
Class<?> errorCodeType = exceptionType.getClassLoader()
                        .loadClass(exceptionType.getName()+"$ErrorCode");
assert errorCodeType.getDeclaringClass() == exceptionType;
```

Then, you can lookup the constructor using

```
Constructor<? extends Exception> con = exceptionType.getConstructor(errorCodeType);
```

But maybe you are thinking too complicated. If you already have your `someErrorCodeEnum` object that you intend to pass to the constructor, you can simply use this object to determine the parameter type:

```
Constructor<? extends Exception> con = exception.getClass()
    .getConstructor(((Enum<?>)someErrorCodeEnum).getDeclaringClass());
```

Note the importance of using `Enum.getDeclaringClass()` rather than `Object.getClass()` here, as a particular `enum` constant may be of an anonymous inner class extending the formal `enum` type. `getDeclaringClass()` will return the right type.

Comment: Thank you! I'm almost there. `Constructor ctor = exception.getClass().getConstructor(((Enum<?>) errorCode).getDeclaringClass());
WhatClassType expectedException = ctor.newInstance(errorCode);`

The type that this constructor may return might be an ExceptionA or ExceptionB, etc. How do I generically specific the return type?

Comment: Isn’t this where a common superclass of your exception classes comes in? As mentioned at the bottom of my (otherwise not to the point) answer.

Comment: Well, if there’s no other common base class than `Exception`, using `Constructor<? extends Exception>` like shown in my answer will be sufficient to assign the result of `newInstance` to variables of type `Exception` or the same type as the `exception` variable, as long as it isn’t a type parameter. If the type of `exception` is a type parameter, there is no type safe way to denote that the result of the Reflection operation will be of the same type. It will be the erasure of the type variable instead. That’s a known limitation of Java Generics.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I got your requirements. I am thinking this ought to be doable without reflection, so here’s my idea:

```
public class ExceptionA extends Exception {

    public ExceptionA(ExceptionA.ErrorCode errorCode) {
    }

    public static enum ErrorCode implements ExceptionErrorCode {
        EC_ABC, EC_XYZ, EC_123;

        @Override
        public Exception toException() {
            return new ExceptionA(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this little interface:

```
public interface ExceptionErrorCode {
    Exception toException();
}
```

This will allow something like:

```
    ExceptionErrorCode someErrorCodeEnum = ExceptionA.ErrorCode.EC_XYZ;
    Exception expectedException = someErrorCodeEnum.toException();
```

Would this fulfil your requirements?

I am thinking for the sake of the model you may want to introduce a common superclass for your exception classes so you need not declare `toException()` and `expectedException` just `Exception` — it’s a vague type for my taste. And even though you don’t see the need immediately, the supertype could come in handy some time.

Comment: There are several exception classes though. MyRuntimeException, MyCheckedException, etc. that all extend the base Exception class.

Comment: I expected that. And yes, you would have to duplicate the override of `toException()` in the enum of each class.